# Status of Jupyter or IPython interactive terminal

Tags: python, linux, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-console

I work on a linux server with no http access. Purely command line. I've decided I'd like to start using ipython, however it seems to have been superseded by jupyter. I've tried googling for ipython tutorials, and just about everything is about browser interactive notebooks. I've tried googling things like "ipython terminal" "jupyter terminal" and just about everything that comes up is terminal options for starting ipython or jupyter.

1. Is an interactive jupyter (or ipython) terminal still something supported/recommended?
2. Suggestions for up-to-date resources?

NOTE: As I was entering tags, one for [`jupyter-console`](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console) which appears to be a 2nd party terminal front end for jupyter notebooks. But it shows very little recent activity.

Comment: Please refer to the this link : http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#decoupled-two-process-model

Comment: Ok, so `jupyter console` is part of the jupyter ecosystem. Just looked pretty inactive (mostly 1-2 years old). Still hard to find tutorials that don't involve notebooks.

Comment: Whats your goal here with ipython because its mostly used for data analysis and for that you need notebooks mostly in end to show your results.

Comment: Yes, data analysis. I like ipython/jupyter console because of the magic like easy shell commands, and also the fantastic autocomplete, both python commands and filenames. I have not used it much--mostly vanilla python. But I'm increasingly finding those additional features useful.